# Traversing and Styling a Table Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some sort of evaluation form using jQuery. It's essentially a grid or matrix in form of a HTML table. There are 2x5 table cells I want to apply click (and later on hover) events to. When clicking a table cell I collect all elements column-wise. The column I have clicked and those to the left (I call this selection bar) I want to apply classes to and columns to the right (this is nar, short for "no bar") I want to remove classes from.

I think I have figured out the selection process, even though it can be improved. It is just that classes are applied even when failing the .hasClass() tests I do.

Some code, if you will. This here is my static HTML template:

```
<tr class="boss">
    <td class="question" rowspan="2">Executing for results</td>
    <td class="radio answer-tail click-tail"></td>
    <td class="radio answer-head click-head"></td>
    <td class="radio"></td>
    <td class="radio"></td>
    <td class="radio"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="employee">
    <td class="radio answer-tail click-tail"></td>
    <td class="radio answer-tail click-tail"></td>
    <td class="radio answer-tail"></td>
    <td class="radio answer-head"></td>
    <td class="radio"></td>
</tr>
```

And this is my .click():

```
$("td.radio").click(function() {
    var bar = $(this).prevUntil("td.question").andSelf();
    var nar = $(this).nextAll("td.click-head, td.click-tail, td.click");
    var row = $(this).parent();
    var bro = null;
    if (row.hasClass("boss")) {
        bro = row.next("tr.employee").children().eq($(this).index() - 1);
    } else if (row.hasClass("employee")) {
        bro = row.prev("tr.boss").children().eq($(this).index() + 1);
    }
    bar.push(bro.prevAll("td.radio").add(bro));
    nar.push(bro.nextAll("td.click-head, td.click-tail, td.click"));
    bar.each(function(i, e) {
        if ($(e).hasClass("answer-head")) {
            $(e).addClass("click-head");
        } else if ($(e).hasClass("answer-tail")) {
            $(e).addClass("click-tail");
        } else {
            $(e).addClass("click");
        }
    });
    nar.each(function(i, e) {
        $(e).removeClass("click-head").removeClass("click-tail").removeClass("click");
    });
});
```

The problem is that this script gives me some curious bugs. I.e., clicking on the the last table cell in the second row will result in this:

```
<tr class="boss">
    <td class="question" rowspan="2">Executing for results</td>
    <td class="radio answer-tail click-tail click-head"></td>
    <td class="radio answer-head click-head"></td>
    <td class="radio click-head"></td>
    <td class="radio click-head"></td>
    <td class="radio click-head"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="employee">
    <td class="radio answer-tail click-tail"></td>
    <td class="radio answer-tail click-tail"></td>
    <td class="radio answer-tail click-tail"></td>
    <td class="radio answer-head click-head"></td>
    <td class="radio click"></td>
</tr>
```

The last the cells in the first row have been given the wrong class. In my bar.each() I check if the current cell has the class .answer-head, and if not it should use .click. This is somehow overridden and .click-head is given anyway.

Why?

Edit: And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tSyLj/ (WebKit-dependent: Chrome or Safari...)

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete http://jsfiddle.net/W6BRa/

Comment: use jquery sortable.. or isotype.. stop wasting your life trying to make your own code..

Comment: @r0m4n: Okay, sorry. Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tSyLj/

Comment: @ppumkin: I will have a look at Sortable.

Comment: @ppumkin: I don't really get how http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ or http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ will help me.

Comment: Dont know.. I just thought it comment on it. It has very powerful sorting abilities.. maybe another plugin could be jlinq.. I am not sure what you are doing .. but you mentioned sort.. and skimming your code gives me a headache.. so there must be an easier way.. hence my comments and no answer

Comment: Okay! I solved on my own now when going through the code for the n:th time. I think it was something with selecting the table cells in the second row. I also got a hover effect working. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: About the headache? Is it really that bad code? This is my first try at jQuery (and JavaScript) and I listen to reason. I hate bad code.